# How can I push or add a list to viewModel

Tags: c#, list, model, viewmodel

1. I have created two list models.
2. Query the DB models to get the list of objects for the two models created.(each returns object list)
3. Created viewModel to return an object.
4. Now I want to map internationalRatesSummaries and specificRatesSummaries
5. I don't know how I can assign/map to the returned object.

**GetRateSheet**

```
                public RateSheetViewModel GetRateSheet(int resellerId)
                {
                
                    foreach (var item in rateSheetDetails)
                    {
                        
                        var internationalSammaries = (from r in _Context.InternationalRatesSummary where r.RateSheetId == item.RateSheetId select r).ToList();

                       
                        var specificSammaries = (from r in _Context.SpecificRatesSummary where r.RateSheetId == item.RateSheetId select r).ToList();

                        var viewModel = new RateSheetViewModel
                        {
                            RateSheetId = item.RateSheetId,
                            ResellerId = item.ResellerId,
                            TarrifId = item.TarrifId,
                            RateSheetName = item.RateSheetName,
                            internationalRatesSummaries = ???????, how do i pass internationalSammaries
                            specificRatesSummaries = ???????? , how do i pass specificSammaries
                        };
                    }
                    return viewModel; //As a results, i cannot return viewModel
                }
```

**ViewModel**

This is the view model which i want to return it to the API

```
                public class RateSheetViewModel
                {
                    public IEnumerable<InternationalRatesSummaries> internationalRatesSummaries { get; set; }
                    public IEnumerable<SpecificRatesSummaries> specificRatesSummaries { get; set; }
                }
```

Comment: `internationalRatesSummaries = internationalSammaries`  should work since List implements IEnumerable.  Same for specificRatesSummaries

Comment: It looks like you need to restructure your data container though.  Your method returns a single viewModel, but you are create many viewModels in the foreach loop.  You could add another data container class, and then in your view model use IEnumerable<MyDataContainer> instead of the enumerable properties which would be moved into MyDataContiner class.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you please illustrate in code so that i can be able to follow your guidlines?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a collection of data in your view model, i created a data container for those properties.

```
public class RateSheetData
{
    public string RateSheetName { get; set; }

    // other sheet data properties..

    public IEnumerable<InternationalRatesSummaries> InternationalRatesSummaries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SpecificRatesSummaries> SpecificRatesSummaries { get; set; }
}
```

and updated the view model to have a collection of that container class.

```
public class RateSheetViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RateSheetData> RateSheetDatas { get; set; }
}
```

And in your controller where you contruct the view model, you create an instance for each of the rateSheetDetails objects.  The example below using Linq to enumerate over the rateSheetDetails creating a new instance of RateSheetData for each item.

```
var datas = rateSheetDetails
    .Select(item => new RateSheetData()
    {
        RateSheetName = item.RateSheetName,

        // Assign other specific properties...

        InternationalRatesSummaries = (from r in _Context.InternationalRatesSummary where r.RateSheetId == item.RateSheetId select r),
        SpecificRatesSummaries = (from r in _Context.SpecificRatesSummary where r.RateSheetId == item.RateSheetId select r)
    })
```

Then assign that collection of RateSheetData to the view model.

```
var viewModel = new RateSheetViewModel()
{
    // other properties..

    RateSheetDatas = datas
};
```

Then in your view you can enumerate over the sheet datas like normal.

```
foreach (var sheetData in Model.RateSheetDatas)
```

Comment: In a view, you mean in angular? It is an angular project.

Comment: That example would be for a purely MVC view, but the idea is the same, the data is contained in that collection (array?) for you to enumerate over when data is receieved.